# Bootstrap 3 two modals switching - scrolling page

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I've got two Bootstrap 3 modals as below. One modal is switching to another - and there is a button - "Go back" to previous modal. Unfortunatelly modals are long and when I'm switching back - scrolling works but for website, not for previous modal. Anyone knows how to fix it?

I'm using the default bootstrap css and js files, google chrome

Complete HTML code as below:

```
<head> 
 <!-- scripts: jquery.min.js; bootstrap.min.js css: bootstrap.min.css -->
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addOffer">Add offer</button>
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewOffer">View offer</button>
```

first modal:

```
<div class="modal fade"  tabindex="-1" id="viewOffer" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">View offer</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        lots of text about offer here: 
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addOffer">Go back</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>     
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

second modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addOffer" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add offer</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        lots of forms for new offer here: 
        <input id= "see_offer" name="see_offer" type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="View offer" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewOffer" />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> 
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're trying to make a submit button to also display a modal. Which is fundamentally wrong right there.

Comment: that's true, submit removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `.modal { overflow-y:auto; }` to your css file.

Answer (score 1):

The regular `data-toggle:"modal"` button will do, as suggested, toggle the modal visibility. The buttons in your page may remain so. However, you seem to want your modal buttons to hide one modal and show another, so set a function to them manually like so:

```
$("[hide-modal]").click(function () {
    $(this).attr("hide-modal").modal("hide");
    $(this).attr("display-modal").modal("show");
});
```

Then in your modal buttons:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" hide-modal="#viewOffer" display-modal="#addOffer">Go back</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" hide-modal="#addOffer" display-modal="#viewOffer">View offer</button>
```

Comment: glad I could help.